# How to call a method in activity from a service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-handler

There is a service that listens for some voice. If voice matches a string a certain method is invoked in the service object.

```
public class SpeechActivationService extends Service {

     public static Intent makeStartServiceIntent(Context pContext){    

         return new Intent(pContext, SpeechActivationService.class);
     }

     //...

     public void onMatch(){
         Log.d(TAG, "voice matches word");
     }

     //...
}
```

This is how I start the service in my activity:

```
Intent i = SpeechActivationService.makeStartServiceIntent(this);
startService(i);
```

From this service method, how can I invoke a method that resides in the activity object? I don't want access from activity to service, but from service to activity. I already read about handlers and broadcasters but could not find/understand any example. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the method have to be in the Activity class, or can you move it into a utility class?

Comment: I want to update the user interface so I think it has to be in activity class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would register a BroadcastReceiver in the Activity and send an Intent to it from the service. 
See this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html
It might look a bit long but you'll want to learn how to use those anyway ;)

Answer (score 69):

Assuming your Service and Activity are in the same package (i.e. the same app), you can use LocalBroadcastManager as follows:

In your Service:

```
// Send an Intent with an action named "my-event". 
private void sendMessage() {
  Intent intent = new Intent("my-event");
  // add data
  intent.putExtra("message", "data");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

In your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("my-event"));
}

// handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event 
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Extract data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  // Unregister since the activity is not visible
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onPause();
}
```

From section 7.3 of @Ascorbin's link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#ownreceiver_localbroadcastmanager

Comment: Thanks Tony!  Great answer

Comment: Simple and direct answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm using the same in my project. It was working fine. Now I'm getting null exception in service class while LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to achive this. One of them to use `Handler` and `Messanger` classes. The idea of the method is to pass `Handler` object from `Activity` to `Service`. Every time `Service` wants to call some method of the `Activity` it just sends a `Message` and `Activity` handles it somehow.

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                showToast(msg.what);
            }
        };

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);

        intent.putExtra("messenger", messenger);
        startService(intent);
    }

    private void showToast(int messageId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message  " + messageId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final Messenger messenger = (Messenger) intent.getParcelableExtra("messenger");
            final Message message = Message.obtain(null, 1234);

            try {
                messenger.send(message);
            } catch (RemoteException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: My service extends from service and not IntentService

Comment: You can use `Service` as well. This code just shows the idea. I updated my answer and now it uses `Service` instead of `IntentService`

Comment: +1 Thank you, I already managed it with broadcast receiver http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/broadcast-receiver-from-activity/

Comment: is there any performance difference in this two approach (messanger vs broadcasting) in case we are sending commands/values from service to activity often, let's say 20 times per second? thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the following timings in my case for sending and receiving the broadcast. I have service in the same process.

sendBroadcast (Not recommended if both components are in same process)
34 sec

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
close to 30 sec

**Implementing using AIDL and RemoteCallbackList**
Will work for same process or different process

In your service

```
public final RemoteCallbackList<ICallBackAidl> mDMCallbacks = new RemoteCallbackList<ICallBackAidl>();

public void registerDMCallback(ICallBackAidl cb) {
    Logger.d(LOG_TAG, "registerDMCallback " + cb);
    if (cb != null)
        mDMCallbacks.register(cb);
}
```

When  you need call methods in Application/Acitvity from service

```
public void callMehodsInApplication() {
    final int N = mDMCallbacks.beginBroadcast();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        try {
            mDMCallbacks.getBroadcastItem(i).method1();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    mDMCallbacks.finishBroadcast();
}
```

In your class extending Application or Activity.

```
private ISyncmlServiceDMCallback mCallback = new ISyncmlServiceDMCallback.Stub() {
 // Implement callback methods here
  public void method1() {
       // Service can call this method
  }
}

 public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {   
        svc.LocalBinder binder = (svc.LocalBinder) service;
        mSvc = binder.getService();
        mSvc.registerDMCallback(mCallback);
 }
```

Calling this way is almost instantaneous from broadcasting and receiving from the same process