# Pass the activity from Application class

Tags: android

I am creating a class in application with following code:

```
public class Trackers extends Application
{
       private static Connection connection;
       public Connection getConnectionInstance() {
           if (connection == null)
               connection = new Connection();
           return connection;
       }
}
```

I need to pass Main activity to `Connection` class.Is this possible ? If it is possible,how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your main activity as a parameter to connection constructor:

```
public class Trackers extends Application
{
       private static Connection connection;

       public Connection getConnectionInstance(MainActivity main) {
           if (connection == null){
               connection = new Connection(main);
           }
           return connection;
       }
}
```

of course, I assume that if you want to pass the activity to Connction, connection needs to support getting the main activity

if you want to call method from activty, look here:
[How to call a method in activity from a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896574/how-to-call-a-method-in-activity-from-a-service)

or here:
[android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

Comment: But I am calling getConnectionInstance from service.Not from main activity.

Comment: @Okan why do you want to pass the main activity? are you sure you dont need the application context only?

Comment: I will call main activity method from connection class.So I need main activity.

Comment: @Okan but if you calling from a service, maybe the main activity isn't active. it's smells like you need to use Intents here

Comment: Can you give an example ? Please I am researching for hours I am so confused.

Comment: @Okan See my edit, good luck (an accepted answer / upvote will be nice)